# Finding eigenvectors with irrational eigenvalues.

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-analysis

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & \frac {69}{28}  \\
        \frac {69}{28} & \frac {15}{7}  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
This is my initial matrix.
So, I calculated my eigenvalues with no problem but got stuck with eigenvectors. 
My eigenvalues are 5.7049 and 0.4380 (they are right - I checked with Matlab).

Then I performed row manipulation and got

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1.70631 & 2.464  \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

And now I don't know what to do to get the correct eigenvectors. There's one free variable so I set $x_1$ as 't' and tried solving for $x_2$ but that gives me the correct answer. According to Matlab, the correct eigenvector should be
 $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -0.8224  \\
        0.5689\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

What do I have to do to get that??

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: An eigenvector isn't unique. Did you get something that is a scalar multiple of what Matlab got?

Comment: Since the eigenvector is only unique upto multiplication with a scalar, you can choose one coordinate free, but not $0$ (for example $x_2=1$). This gives an eigenvector colinear with the one given by Matlab.

Comment: Matlab seems to have normalised its vector so that it is a unit vector

Comment: To get a unit vector (See Mark's comment), just didvide the vector you have calculated by its length. Upto possibly a sign, this gives you the vector given by Matlab.

Comment: I did not know that Matlab automatically normalizes the eigenvector. That solves it! Thanks a lot!!